# Unable to run Ubuntu Desktop GUI on Xilinx's ZCU104

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, displayport, xilinx

I am trying to boot a Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS image on my Xilinx ZCU104 platform. While I am able to login using the serial port, I am unable to view the GUI on my monitor. I see some boot commands and then the screen goes black. I have a few questions -

1. Which port of the ZCU104 gives the GUI output feed? The ZCU104 has 2 HDMI ports and 1 display port. I tried using all of them but nothing worked out for me, except seeing a few bootup commands on one of the HDMI displays. I have a HDMI monitor. Should I buy one with display port?
2. Why am I seeing the boot commands and then the screen goes black? If the display or the cable are bad then I should not see even this right?

Let me know if anything else is needed to debug this issue.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 desktop image, Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format (they are *snap* only and intended for headless operation such as Ubuntu Core 20) and different products that use the *year.month* format which are *deb* based, and include server & desktop products, such as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop). Your tagged 20.04 is a different product to a Ubuntu Core 20 which is not intended for desktop use.  20 != 20.04

Comment: I seem to have miscommunicated the name of the image I am using. I edited the question accordingly. I am using the image provided on this site and the link clearly says it supports Xilinx ZCU104: https://ubuntu.com/download/xilinx
I contacted the Xilinx support and it is mostly related to me using an HDMI monitor and not one with a display port.

Comment: Unfortunately you're on your own here because the image that you linked to is not an official Ubuntu version from Canonical.